# ArgumentError in Application#hhome Nil location provided. Can't build URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a Rails app, and am using active admin with Carrierwave.
I want to load an image into CSS, so I tried this

```
<% @headCarousel.each do |carousel| %>
    <li style="background-image: url('<%= image_tag carousel.image.url %>');">
<%end%>
```

I want to post the image saved in loaded through ActiveAdmin to this list.
How do I do it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need no image_tag because it returns an HTML image tag:

```
image_tag("icon.png")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/icon.png" />
```

Background-image need only url:

```
<% @headCarousel.each do |carousel| %>
  <li style="background-image: url('<%= carousel.image.url %>');">
<%end%>
```

If its not helped check what url you are get in carousel.image.url:

```
<% @headCarousel.each do |carousel| %>
  <li><%= carousel.image.url %></li>
<%end%>
```